# Prolog binary search tree test - unwanted parents' parent node comparison

Tags: prolog, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm a Prolog rookie, please keep that in mind.
I try to write a predicate to determine if some given term is a binary search tree. I figured out this code:

```
is_btree(nil).
is_btree(node(N,L,R)) :-
   number(N),
   is_btree(L), 
   is_btree(R), 
   small(N, R),
   big(N, L).

small(N, nil).
small(N, node(M,L,R)) :-
   N < M,
   small(N, L),
   small(N, R).

big(N, nil).
big(N, node(M,L,R)) :-
   N > M,
   big(N, L),
   big(N, R).
```

It works quite fine until I test a graph that has a node on the right side which passes the condition "higher than parent node", but it is higher or equal to parent node of the parent node. In this case Prolog reports failure.

Here is a sample query which fails unexpectedly:

```
?- is_btree(node(9,node( 3,node( 2,nil,nil),
                           node(10,nil,nil)),
                   node(12,node( 8,nil,nil),
                           node(15,nil,nil)))).
false.
```

A very similar problem arises when some node on the left side is higher than parent node of the parent node—a situation that is shown in the following illustration:

[image]

How can I check node values only with the value of their immediate parent node, but not the values of parents' parents?

Comment: but it should fail. that tree is an invalid BST and your predicate tests for *valid* BSTs.

Comment: Shall we use explicit interval arithmetic? (Ab-)using FD domains appeared to be an option too, but *that* is too hackish for my taste. Using **2** FD variables (Alpha, Omega) for intervals seems more promising...

Comment: @repeat I'm going to stick with the simple stuff in my answer. :)

Comment: @WillNess. It 2am: High time for me to start evangelizing:)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slightly different take on the problem you want to solve.

1. [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) for collecting elements: in-order [tree-traversal](/questions/tagged/tree-traversal)

   ```
   in_order(nil) --> [].
   in_order(node(X,L,R)) --> in_order(L), [X], in_order(R).
   ```
2. [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) for relating adjacent [list](/questions/tagged/list) elements (which are all finite-domain variables)

   ```
   chain(Zs, #<)
   ```

Let's put it all together and define `is_bintreeFD/1` like this:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

is_bintreeFD(T) :-
   phrase(in_order(T), Zs),
   chain(Zs, #<).
```

Sample queries:

```
?- is_bintreeFD(node(9,node( 3,node(2,nil,nil),node(10,nil,nil)),
                       node(12,node(8,nil,nil),node(15,nil,nil)))).
false.

?- is_bintreeFD(node(9,node( 3,node( 2,nil,nil),node( 8,nil,nil)),
                       node(12,node(10,nil,nil),node(15,nil,nil)))).
true.
```

Comment: nice! is it possible to switch the two goals, so the traversal is stopped as soon as possible on failure? to have `chain` before the `phrase`?

Answer (score 3):

This answer directly follows up on [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34698899/4609915), particularly on a comment by @WillNess that suggested "[...] *switch the two goals, so the traversal is stopped as soon as possible on failure* [...] *to have `chain` before the `phrase`* [...]".

`lazy_chain/2` is like `chain/2`, but utilizes [prolog-coroutining](/questions/tagged/prolog-coroutining) to wait for sufficient instantiation:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

lazy_chain(Zs, R_2) :-
   (  var(R_2)                  -> instantiation_error(R_2)
   ;  clpfd:chain_relation(R_2) -> freeze(Zs, lazy_chain_aux(Zs,R_2))
   ;  otherwise                 -> domain_error(chain_relation, R_2)
   ).

lazy_chain_aux([], _).
lazy_chain_aux([Z0|Zs], R_2) :-
   freeze(Zs, lazy_chain_aux_(Zs,R_2,Z0)).

lazy_chain_aux_([], _, _).
lazy_chain_aux_([Z1|Zs], R_2, Z0) :-
   call(R_2, Z0, Z1),
   freeze(Zs, lazy_chain_aux_(Zs,R_2,Z1)).
```

Based on `lazy_chain/2` we define `is_bintreeL/2` like this:

```
is_bintreeL(T) :-
   lazy_chain(Zs, #<),
   phrase(in_order(T), Zs).
```

So... what about "early failure"?

```
?- T = node(2, nil, node(1, nil, node(3, nil, node(4, nil, node(5, nil, node(6, nil, node(7, nil, node(8, nil, node(9, nil, node(10, nil, node(11, nil, node(12, nil, node(13, nil, node(14, nil, node(15, nil, node(16, nil, node(17, nil, node(18, nil, node(19, nil, node(20, nil, node(21, nil, node(22, nil, node(23, nil, node(24, nil, node(25, nil, node(26, nil, node(27, nil, node(28, nil, node(29, nil, node(30, nil, node(31, nil, node(32, nil, node(33, nil, node(34, nil, node(35, nil, node(36, nil, node(37, nil, node(38, nil, node(39, nil, node(40, nil, node(41, nil, node(42, nil, node(43, nil, node(44, nil, node(45, nil, node(46, nil, node(47, nil, node(48, nil, node(49, nil, node(50, nil, node(51, nil, node(52, nil, node(53, nil, node(54, nil, node(55, nil, node(56, nil, node(57, nil, node(58, nil, node(59, nil, node(60, nil, node(61, nil, node(62, nil, node(63, nil, node(64, nil, node(65, nil, node(66, nil, node(67, nil, node(68, nil, node(69, nil, node(70, nil, node(71, nil, node(72, nil, node(73, nil, node(74, nil, node(75, nil, node(76, nil, node(77, nil, node(78, nil, node(79, nil, node(80, nil, node(81, nil, node(82, nil, node(83, nil, node(84, nil, node(85, nil, node(86, nil, node(87, nil, node(88, nil, node(89, nil, node(90, nil, node(91, nil, node(92, nil, node(93, nil, node(94, nil, node(95, nil, node(96, nil, node(97, nil, node(98, nil, node(99, nil, node(100, nil, nil)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))),
   time((phrase(in_order(T),Zs),eager_chain(Zs,#<))).
% 210 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (98% CPU, 4100201 Lips)
false.

?- T = node(2, nil, node(1, nil, node(3, nil, node(4, nil, node(5, nil, node(6, nil, node(7, nil, node(8, nil, node(9, nil, node(10, nil, node(11, nil, node(12, nil, node(13, nil, node(14, nil, node(15, nil, node(16, nil, node(17, nil, node(18, nil, node(19, nil, node(20, nil, node(21, nil, node(22, nil, node(23, nil, node(24, nil, node(25, nil, node(26, nil, node(27, nil, node(28, nil, node(29, nil, node(30, nil, node(31, nil, node(32, nil, node(33, nil, node(34, nil, node(35, nil, node(36, nil, node(37, nil, node(38, nil, node(39, nil, node(40, nil, node(41, nil, node(42, nil, node(43, nil, node(44, nil, node(45, nil, node(46, nil, node(47, nil, node(48, nil, node(49, nil, node(50, nil, node(51, nil, node(52, nil, node(53, nil, node(54, nil, node(55, nil, node(56, nil, node(57, nil, node(58, nil, node(59, nil, node(60, nil, node(61, nil, node(62, nil, node(63, nil, node(64, nil, node(65, nil, node(66, nil, node(67, nil, node(68, nil, node(69, nil, node(70, nil, node(71, nil, node(72, nil, node(73, nil, node(74, nil, node(75, nil, node(76, nil, node(77, nil, node(78, nil, node(79, nil, node(80, nil, node(81, nil, node(82, nil, node(83, nil, node(84, nil, node(85, nil, node(86, nil, node(87, nil, node(88, nil, node(89, nil, node(90, nil, node(91, nil, node(92, nil, node(93, nil, node(94, nil, node(95, nil, node(96, nil, node(97, nil, node(98, nil, node(99, nil, node(100, nil, nil)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))),
   time((lazy_chain(Zs,#<),phrase(in_order(T),Zs))).
% 52 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (98% CPU, 1225664 Lips)
false.
```

Laziness wins—at least in above case:)

Note, however, that using `lazy_chain/2` with [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) can lead to bugs that are hard to find!

For a more robust solution, see [this alternative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34705918/4609915)...

---

For the sake of completeness, here's the source code of `eager_chain/2`:

```
eager_chain(Zs, R_2) :-
   (  var(R_2)                  -> instantiation_error(R_2)
   ;  clpfd:chain_relation(R_2) -> eager_chain_aux(Zs, R_2)
   ;  otherwise                 -> domain_error(chain_relation, R_2)
   ).

eager_chain_aux([], _).
eager_chain_aux([Z0|Zs], R_2) :-
   eager_chain_aux_(Zs, R_2, Z0).

eager_chain_aux_([], _, _).
eager_chain_aux_([Z1|Zs], R_2, Z0) :-
   call(R_2, Z0, Z1),
   eager_chain_aux_(Zs, R_2, Z1).
```

Answer (score 2):

In this answer we **use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)
for declarative integer arithmetics**.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

:- asserta(clpfd:full_answer).
```

We define the predicates `is_bintree/1` and `bintree_in/2` like this:

```
is_bintree(T) :-
   bintree_in(T, _).

bintree_in(nil, LB-UB) :-            % LB-UB denotes the open interval (LB,UB)
   LB #< UB.                         % that is all integers I suchthat LB<I<UB
bintree_in(node(Mid,L,R), LB-UB) :-
   Mid #> LB,
   Mid #< UB,
   bintree_in(L, LB-Mid),
   bintree_in(R, Mid-UB).
```

First, we test<sup>1,2</sup> the tree given by the OP:

```
| ?- bintree_in(node(9,node( 3,node(2,nil,nil),node(10,nil,nil)),
                       node(12,node(8,nil,nil),node(15,nil,nil))), _).
no
```

Let's fix the tree and check again!

```
| ?- bintree_in(node(9,node( 3,node( 2,nil,nil),node( 8,nil,nil)),
                       node(12,node(10,nil,nil),node(15,nil,nil))), _).
_A in inf..1, _B in 16..sup ? ;      % (somewhat sloppy)
no
```

OK! Next up are a few corner cases:

```
| ?- bintree_in(T, 0-0).             % no solution (as expected)
no
| ?- bintree_in(T, 0-1).             % empty tree
T = nil ? ;
no
| ?- bintree_in(T, 0-2).             % singleton tree
T = nil ? ;
T = node(1,nil,nil) ? ;
no
```

Note that while `is_btree/1` can only "test", `bintree_in/2` can *both<sup>3</sup>* "test" and "generate"!

So let's generate (all possible) binary trees of a certain size in a small domain:

```
| ?- bintree_in(T, 0-3).             % T has less than 3 elements
T = nil ? ;
T = node(_A,nil,nil), _A in 1..2 ? ;
T = node(1,nil,node(2,nil,nil)) ? ;
T = node(2,node(1,nil,nil),nil) ? ;
no

| ?- bintree_in(T, 0-4).             % T has less than 4 elements
T = nil ? ;
T = node(_A,nil,nil), _A in 1..3 ? ;
T = node(_A,nil,node(_B,nil,nil)), _A#=<_B+ -1, _B#>=_A+1, _B in 2..3, _A in 1..2 ? ;
T = node(1,nil,node(2,nil,node(3,nil,nil))) ? ;
T = node(1,nil,node(3,node(2,nil,nil),nil)) ? ;
T = node(_A,node(_B,nil,nil),nil), _A#>=_B+1, _A in 2..3, _B in 1..2 ? ;
T = node(2,node(1,nil,nil),node(3,nil,nil)) ? ; 
T = node(3,node(1,nil,node(2,nil,nil)),nil) ? ;
T = node(3,node(2,node(1,nil,nil),nil),nil) ? ;
no
```

Last, we generate candidate solutions with `bintree_in/2` and test these with `is_btree/1`!

`is_btree/1` needs sufficient instantiation; `labeling/2` provides us with ground terms.

```
| ?- call_time((  UB in 2..12, 
                  indomain(UB),
                  bintree_in(T, 0-UB),
                  term_variables(T, Zs),
                  labeling([], Zs),
                  \+ is_btree(T)
               ;  true
               ),
               T_ms).
T_ms = 6270 ? ;
no
```

---

<sup>**Footnote 1:**
The code in this answer runs (at on [sicstus-prolog](/questions/tagged/sicstus-prolog) and [swi-prolog](/questions/tagged/swi-prolog).


**Footnote 2:**
All [prolog-toplevel](/questions/tagged/prolog-toplevel) output presented is that of 
SICStus Prolog 4.3.2 (64-bit).


**Footnote 3:**
Not just do both, but 
*(almost) arbitrarily mix* generate and test, as it can handle partially instantiated terms.</sup>

Comment: Wow, thanks for solutions, but i really just thought that this type of tree can be also valid... :D  sorry guys

Answer (score 2):

In a comment to [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34698899/4609915), @WillNess suggested adding "early-failure" as a feature.

`in_order_inf_sup//3` effectively combines [`in_order//1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34698899/4609915) and
[`chain/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=chain/2):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

in_order_inf_sup(nil, P, P) --> [].
in_order_inf_sup(node(X,L,R), P0, P) -->
   in_order_inf_sup(L, P0, P1),
   [X],
   { P1 #< X },
   in_order_inf_sup(R, X, P).
```

Sample queries (same as in previous answer):

```
?- phrase(in_order_inf_sup(node(9,node( 3,node(2,nil,nil),node(10,nil,nil)),
                                  node(12,node(8,nil,nil),node(15,nil,nil))),_,_),
          Zs).
false.

?- phrase(in_order_inf_sup(node(9,node( 3,node( 2,nil,nil),node( 8,nil,nil)),
                                  node(12,node(10,nil,nil),node(15,nil,nil))),_,_),
          Zs).
Zs = [2,3,8,9,10,12,15].
```

Answer (score 1):

But it *should* fail. That tree is an invalid BST and your predicate tests for valid BSTs.

There is something to be done here though. Right now you perform two passes over a tree - first in `is_btree`, second, with `small`/`big`.

The two can be fused into one, but an immediately apparent solution will do exactly what you want, and thus succeed on such invalid BSTs:

```
is_bst(nil).

is_bst(node(N,L,R)):- 
   (  L = nil 
   ;  L = node(M,LL,LR), M < N, is_bst(L), ....
   ),
   (  R = nil
   ;  ...... 
   ).
```

To fix it, we have to return one more result from the tree traversal — that is the tree's rightmost element — and use *it* in the comparisons for validation.

(*edit:* missed that the leftmost element also needs to be returned)